# Runtime comparison between merge sort, insertion sort and recursive insertion sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

```
def merge_sort(unorderedList):
    if len(unorderedList) > 1:
        mid = len(unorderedList) // 2 
        left = unorderedList[:mid]
        right = unorderedList[mid:]
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                unorderedList[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                unorderedList[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(left):
            unorderedList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(right):
            unorderedList[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

```
def insertion_sort(list1):
    for i in range(1, len(list1)):
        key = list1[i]
        j = i - 1 
        while j >= 0 and list1[j] > key:
            list1[j + 1] = list1[j]
            j -= 1
        list1[j + 1] = key
```

```
def recursive_insertion_sort(arr, n):
    if n <= 1:
        return

    recursive_insertion_sort(arr, n-1)
    last = arr[n-1]
    j = n-2
     
    while j >= 0 and arr[j] > last:
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
        j -= 1
 
    arr[j + 1] = last
```

```
import time
import random
t0 = time.time()
insertion_sort([random.randint(-10000, 10000) for i in range(50000)])
t1 = time.time()
recursive_insertion_sort([random.randint(-10000, 10000) for i in range(50000)])
t2 = time.time()
merge_sort([random.randint(-10000, 10000) for i in range(50000)])
t3 = time.time()

print("insertion sort timer : ", t1 - t0)
print("recursive insertion sort timer : ", t2 - t1)
print("merge sort timer : ", t3 - t2)
```

I used these three functions to compare their runtimes on a 50 thousand membered random list
And i got these times with python 3.10 in vscode

**insertion sort timer : 78.13s

recursive insertion sort timer : 0.068s

merge sort timer : 0.209s**
Is this correct? And if so, can you explain it please?
Considering merge sort has an order of O(nlogn) and insertion sorts order is O(n^2), how is this happening?

#### EDIT: added the code and method used for time testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these functions are performing an "inplace" sort, I suspect that your metrics were not starting from the same original list.

For example, if you test merge_sort first on list `A` and then test insertion_sort on `A`, that second sort gets an already sorted list which that algorithm should benefit from.  This is likely what happened between the "insertion sort" measurement and the "recursive insertion sort" measurement.

Theoretically, recursive_insertion_sort function shouldn't be able to sort any list with more than 990 items. So, I'm guessing you changed the maximum recursion depth limit (if you didn't then something else is wrong in the experiment)

If you test each sort independently (or on copies of the original list), you should get very different results.

Comment: Actually all lists are created using random integers (random.randint) between -10000 and 10000, and each function is getting its own list as argument.

Comment: Could you post the code you used for the performance measurements.  The test I did don't match the numbers you are getting.  They are more in line with the expected complexity levels.

Comment: I did that and edited the question, I'll test it with timeit module and report those results too ASAP.